# Stroboscope's unit

Tags: units, rotation, electronics

Can someone please tell me why does stroboscope's unit is rps or rpm. Revolution per minute/second. Although the stroboscope used was an electronic stroboscope. Is it has something to do with the inside component of the stroboscope which it rotates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stroboscopes we had at school, in a largely pre-electronic age, were simply rotating discs with a hole near the edge.  You shone a light at the edge, and the RPM of the disc determined how rapidly the strobe would flash (as the hole passed in front of the light).

Answer (score 1):

It comes from the fact that most strobes are, or were, used to examine car engines. [Specifically the distributor](http://www.volksworld.com/tech-guides/vw-diy-guides/setting-ignition-timing-with-a-strobe-3584). Hence RPM